# PostGIS extension not installing

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-13

hello i was trying to install postgis to one of my database with the following command

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

but it returned an error of

ERROR:

> could not open extension control file "/Library/PostgreSQL/13/share/postgresql/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory

how do i install postgis without it giving an error?

UPDATE:
I have tried it on the default databases postgres.app gives you which is your desktop username(mine is aarushsharma), i tried to do

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

and it worked so i think it is a problem to do with my specific postgres user

Comment: How did you install Postgres? Have you downloaded/installed the PostGIS package? Are you running the `CREATE EXTENSION postgis` as a superuser?

Comment: i installed it through the postgres app. I don't know how to get the POSTGIS package. yes i am running it as postgres which has all the superuser permissions

Comment: Postgres app does not really tell me anything. What OS are you on, where did you get Postgres from?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver i am on macOS and i downloaded postgres from here https://postgresapp.com/#:~:text=Postgres.app%20is%20a%20full-featured%20PostgreSQL%20installation%20packaged%20as,user%20interface%20and%20a%20convenient%20menu%20bar%20item.

Comment: In `psql` what does `\dx` show? Does "/Library/PostgreSQL/13/share/postgresql/extension/postgis.control" exist? Do you have more then one installation of Postgres on this machine?

Comment: @eshirvana, Postgres.app includes PostGIS, so downloading it is not necessary.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver i did \dx and this is what it gave
                       List of installed extensions
   Name    | Version |   Schema   |               Description               
-----------+---------+------------+-----------------------------------------
 adminpack | 2.1     | pg_catalog | administrative functions for PostgreSQL
 plpgsql   | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
(2 rows)

Comment: The presence of `adminpack` leads me to believe you are working with an install from here [EDB](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads) not the `Postgres.app`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver i did also install pgadmin before but then i deleted it  maybe that has something to do with the adminpack

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first you need to download and install Postgis if you haven't , [follow this](https://postgis.net/install/).

if you are on Linux , you have to install 2 packages ,`postgis` and `postgresql-13-postgis-3`

only PostGIS 3,0 and above works with Postgresql 13 :

commands on Debian based distros ( I installed from PostgreSQL repository) :

```
sudo apt install postgis postgresql-13-postgis-3
```

on mac you can install it via `brew` by running this command in terminal:

```
brew install postgis
```

if you don't have `brew` installed then install it first :

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

If you have installed using `postgressApp`, Open the Terminal and enter the following two commands:
actually first follow step 3 from Installing Postgres.app documentation:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/paths.d &&
echo /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin | sudo tee /etc/paths.d/postgresapp
```

then :

```
psql -d DATABASE_NAME -f /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/[Postgresqlversion]/share/postgresql/contrib/postgis-[PostGisVersion]/postgis.sql

psql -d DATABASE_NAME -f /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/[Postgresqlversion]/share/postgresql/contrib/postgis-[PostGisVersion]/spatial_ref_sys.sql
```

then you should be able to enable the extension :

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

Comment: hi i am on mac so is there a different command for mac

Comment: @aarush_s see my updated answer , added instruction for Mac OS , hopefully that solve the issue

Comment: it gives an error when i do psql -d fudo -f /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/13.2/share/postgresql/contrib/postgis-3.1.1/postgis.sql -U postgres of 

psql: error: /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/13.2/share/postgresql/contrib/postgis-3.1.1/postgis.sql: No such file or directory

Comment: hmm... can you find any part of that path in you file manager (dolphin)? or have you other installation of postgresql from other method? If yes I suggest remove them and reinstall

Comment: i did install pgadmin does that clash with postgres?

Comment: Probably not , I don’t think that is a problem

Comment: i have just also tried on my other laptop which runs on ubuntu 20.04 and it still gives the same error but instead of 13 it says 12

Comment: then run the same command but instead of 13 put 12 : `sudo apt install postgis postgresql-12-postgis-3`

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error on Windows + Postgres 14.

On Windows you have to launch "Application Stack Builder" and add extension Postgis as said here : http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=postgis_tut01

then you should be able to create the extension.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with Ubuntu/Debian and PostgreSQL14

```
apt install postgis
apt install postgresql-14-postgis-scripts
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```