# postgis extension install fails to find file though it exists

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Working on macOS / catalina

Did a binary install with postgis, but having some trouble. Downloaded both postgresSQL and postgis with homebrew, seemingly successful

Ran `psql -U postgres` and then ran `CREATE EXTENSION postgis` but got the error:

> [ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/Library/PostgreSQL/13/share/postgresql/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory

thought it was because my install was in my homebrew cellar directory, so I just copied it over to the above directory the create extension command went to, but when I re-login and rerun the create extension command, it gives me back the same error even though the file now exists in `"/Library/PostgreSQL/13/share/postgresql/extension"` - can't understand why this is happening / how the system is thinking when it gives this error, is this because it can't access the directory due to permissions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostGIS extension not installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66411176/postgis-extension-not-installing)

Comment: So I did go through that, but the issue still exists unfortunately

Comment: if you run `brew info postgis` , what's the output?